# Question on Virtual Serial port Windows driver

Tags: winapi, driver, umdf

Regarding the sample in https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/serial/VirtualSerial2.

In queue.c there's EvIoRead that is called when an app requests data from my virtual driver. When there's no data, this code is executed:

```
OID
EvtIoRead(
_In_  WDFQUEUE          Queue,
_In_  WDFREQUEST        Request,
_In_  size_t            Length
)
{
....
if (bytesCopied > 0) {
    //
    // Data was read from buffer succesfully
    //
    WdfRequestCompleteWithInformation(Request, status, bytesCopied);
    return;
}
else {
    //
    // No data to read. Queue the request for later processing.
    //
    status = WdfRequestForwardToIoQueue(Request,
                        queueContext->ReadQueue);
    }
}
```

`WdfRequestForwardToIoQueue` is called. However I'm not sure on what to do when there is new data. How do I trigger the `EvtIoRead` to be called again?

Comment: you must not try `EvtIoRead` to be called again - this is wrong. this callback called when somebody try read data from your driver. if you have no data - you not complete request but put it to io queue (`WdfRequestForwardToIoQueue`) when you got new data - you need extract request from io queue and complete it

Comment: in example - when new data - request removed from queue via `WdfIoQueueRetrieveNextRequest(
                            queueContext->ReadQueue,
                            &savedRequest);` and put back for handle via `WdfRequestForwardToIoQueue(
                            savedRequest,
                            Queue)` - at this time `EvtIoRead` callled with this request

Comment: but really after call `WdfIoQueueRetrieveNextRequest` you need copy data  to request and complete it `WdfRequestCompleteWithInformation`.

Answer (score 0):

Just answering hoping that it would be helpful for somebody.
On Read, you have done WdfRequestForwardToIoQueue to queue the request. This time application ReadFile shall be in waiting state. When data ready in driver, get queued previous request and copy the data to that request.